# How do I use Express and Ampersand simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, d3.js, ampersand.js

I'm creating a D3 app that's going to display some simple data using an Express server, and Ampersand on the client side.  Eventually, I'll want to send the data to the browser dynamically, as the entire dataset could get very large.  For now, though, I'm having trouble getting even the simplest of things working.

I've set up a simple Express server, and it's rather simple:

```
// Boilerplate express code 
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express(); 
var path = require('path'); 

// Make the Public directory available to the browser 
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 

app.get('/', function(req, res) { 
  res.sendFile('d3.html', {'root': path.join(__dirname, '/views') }); 
}); 

// Listen on port 3000 
app.listen(3000);
```

That works rather well.  When I visit the page, it loads a blank D3 bar graph (just the axis), but shows no data.  This is because I've not sent the data to the browser, and, as I understand it, this needs to be done using either AJAX, jQuery, or something else.  I'm not sure how to proceed with this.

This is in my d3.html; it reads its data from data.tsv, which I've placed in the `public` folder of my Express server:

```
d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);
```

This is `data.tsv`:

```
letter  frequency
A .08167
B .01492
C .02782
D .04253
E .12702
F .02288
G .02015
H .06094
I .06966
J .00153
K .00772
L .04025
M .02406
N .06749
O .07507
P .01929
Q .00095
R .05987
S .06327
T .09056
U .02758
V .00978
W .02360
X .00150
Y .01974
Z .00074
```

How do I pass the data to the browser so that `d3.html` can read in the data? I don't care if the data is in `data.tsv` or not; I just need to send the equivalent data somehow.  I'm not familiar with it, but I have a hunch that Ampersand can handle the requesting/receiving of this data, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: You can put the data in your actual HTML file in Javascript format and then use a little Javascript in the page to hook the data up to the chart?  Or, you can create a new route in Express to provide the data (probably as JSON) and then make an ajax call from your web page to retrieve the data from the server and then hook the data up to the chart.  If the data is known at the time the page is rendered and it will always be used, it is usually faster to just put it in the original page rather than require the extra ajax call go request it.

Comment: The data is going to be continuously updated.  I understand that I can simply use an AJAX call, but how does Ampersand figure into this?  It seems as if Ampersand handles this sort of data transfer.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know ampersand and their website is absolutely horrible at describing what kinds of problems it is actually most useful for.

Comment: I agree with you there. Unfortunately, though, I am required to use it.  Their website obfuscates any potentially useful information by using hipstery analogies and "cool" phrases throughout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use ampersand for this specific example, in fact, I wouldn't use it at all for this specific problem (and I'm an ampersand author).

What you're trying to do is load the data.tsv file off the server, and get the data in to d3. Normally you'll grab data from a server from the browser with an ajax request (as you identified). And in fact, d3 is already doing that for you. That `d3.tsv` function you're calling is trying to load the `data.tsv` file from the server and parse it for you.

Now, this is obviously not working for you for some reason, so things to look at:

1. If you visit http://localhost:3000/data.tsv, can you see the data in your browser? This checks that you have express + express static setup to properly serve the data.
2. If you open up the d3.html page and open your browser developer tools, do you see any errors?
3. This code is where you are grabbing the data from the server and parsing it. Try logging the `error` to the console and check the developer tools logs to see if there's an error. Maybe d3 is struggling to grab or parse the data? You could log the data too and see if it looks correct at that point:

   ```
   d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
     console.log("The error is:", error); //add these
     console.log("The data is:", error);  //two lines
     x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
     y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.frequency; })]);
   ```
4. Beyond that, you'll need to post more of your d3 code to help people figure out what's going on, and why you aren't getting data. You may even wish to tag this as a d3 question, and remove ampersand from the title as it's probably not relevant to your issue here.

Side note: apologies that the ampersand website wasn't helpful. These things can always be better huh? :)

Comment: And if you do end up using ampersand for other places in your app, you might want to try reading http://read.humanjavascript.com/ as it basically takes you through what all the pieces are (free to read online).

Comment: This helped a ton! I assumed that it was an Express issue, or that I needed something like Ampersand, because those are the things that I'm most unfamiliar with.  However, after looking at the error messages and the data, I found out that each of the tabs in the .tsv file was actually two spaces, which was caused by my ViM configuration.  After fixing that, it works perfectly! Now I'm on to learning the Ampersand side of things, and getting it to update dynamically...